# How to change Bootstrap's classic mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new in Bootstrap. Can you guys give me some advice on how to edit a Bootstrap mobile menu like http://apple.com website when resize to its mobile breakpoint. It's really cool with animations. I want my Bootstrap site to look different. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a coding as service platform... please provide code of what you have so far. See [Creating a Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap mobile menu icon is generated with:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
</button>
```

Notice, the `data-target` to collapse:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" class="nav-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
```

Now, Edit or Add animations of your choice.